# NppExec plugin - where to set command line arguments - npp_exec "script name" param_1 "param 2"

Tags: notepad++, nppexec

NppExec dochelp says:

> - Now the NPP_EXEC command can pass arguments to the script. These arguments   can be accessed in the script through the following
>     macro-variables:  `$(ARGC)`, `$(ARGV)`, `$(ARGV[n])`.  Example:  `npp_exec
>     "script name" param_1 "param 2"`.  This example sets the following
>     values for the script:  `$(ARGC) = 3;  $(ARGV) = param_1 "param 2"; 
>     $(ARGV[0]) = script name;  $(ARGV[1]) = param_1;  $(ARGV[2]) = param
>     2.`

But I am not sure where to set it up. Is it in Execute box or in Advanced Option?

For example,

```
  # counter_thread.rb
count = 0
counter_thread = Thread.new do
  1.upto(1000000) { count += 1; }
end

counter_thread.join unless ARGV[0]
puts "The counter was able to count up to #{count}."
```

Test 1 : NppExec runs this fine since no argument

```
counter_thread.rb
The counter was able to count up to 1000000.
```

Test 2 : Would like to know settings for the one below . 
(dont_call_join is an argument here)

```
counter_thread.rb dont_call_join
```

Comment: @Abbas Do you need help with [tag:nppexec] or are you just serially editing questions? :)

Comment: @muntoo I created a nppexec tag and have been updating nppexec questions so I suppose the latter :).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming counter_thread.rb is a file that is currently open in Notepad++, then `ruby counter_thread.rb dont_call_join` will pass dont_call_join as an argument into Ruby in the usual way (i.e. via `ARVG`).

This will run your code as you seem to expect -- if you pass in an argument to the Ruby program, the counting thread does not run, otherwise it runs.

Perhaps this is the better example?

```
      inputbox "What is your name?" : Nobody    
      ruby -e "puts \"Hello #{ARGV[0]}!\" " $(INPUT[1])
```

The first line pops up a message box to get the user input (defaults to Nobody).
The second line passes user input to the ruby one liner program.
NppExec facilitates.